# AIX : sed command to delete pattern for all the lines except the first

Tags: sed, gnuplot, aix

With AIX 7.X, I've those lines for my gnuplot script :

```
set terminal png truecolor size 1950, 650  background rgb "#eff1f0" 
set output "/xxx/xxxx/xxx/xxx/xxx.png"
set datafile separator ';'

set size ratio 0.2
set bmargin at screen 0.2
unset key
set datafile separator ";"
set ylabel " MB BLOCK " font ",10" offset -1,0
set xlabel font ",10"
set xtics rotate by 45  offset -0.8,-9,-1.8


plot "xx/xx/file.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5, \ 
plot "xx/xx/file.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5, \ 
plot "xx/xx/file.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5, \ 
plot "xx/xx/file.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5, \ 
plot "xx/xx/file.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5, \ 
plot "xx/xx/file.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5, \ 
plot "xx/xx/file.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5, \ 
plot "xx/xx/file.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5, \ 
plot "xx/xx/file.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5, \ 
plot "xx/xx/file.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5, \ 
plot "xx/xx/file.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5, \ 
plot "xx/xx/file.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5, \ 
plot "xx/xx/file.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5
```

I want to delete the pattern " plot " for all the lines, except the first... With my linux I do this :

```
sed '0,/plot/! s/plot//g' myfile.txt
```

And the result is :

```
set terminal png truecolor size 1950, 650  background rgb "#eff1f0" 
set output "/var/IBMtools/www/tim/used.png"
set datafile separator ';'

set size ratio 0.2
set bmargin at screen 0.2
unset key
set datafile separator ";"
set ylabel " MB BLOCK " font ",10" offset -1,0
set xlabel font ",10"
set xtics rotate by 45  offset -0.8,-9,-1.8


plot "xx/xx/file.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5, \ 
 "xx/xx/file.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5, \ 
 "xx/xx/file.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5, \ 
 "xx/xx/file.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5, \ 
 "xx/xx/file.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5, \ 
 "xx/xx/file.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5, \ 
 "xx/xx/file.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5, \ 
 "xx/xx/file.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5, \ 
 "xx/xx/file.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5, \ 
 "xx/xx/file.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5, \ 
 "xx/xx/file.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5, \ 
 "xx/xx/file.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5, \ 
 "xx/xx/file.txt" using 3:xtic(1) title column(2) with linespoints linewidth 2 pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5
```

But this command doesn't works with AIX. The error is `sed: 0602-403 0,/plot/! s/plot//g is not a recognized function.`

Please, could you show me how to do that ?

Comment: Could you try like `seq 3 | sed -n '1,2p'`? `seq 3 | sed -n '1,/2/p'`? `seq 3 | sed '1,/2/s/1/a/'`? Och, I think the `0` as the address is not posix, would the `sed '1,/plot/!s/plot//'` work?

Comment: Hello, I've add some details to be more clear !

Comment: @HK2432, Could you please do lemme know if my solution has helped you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If plot is not in the first line in the file, you could do this:

```
sed '1,/plot/!s/plot//'
```

If it can be on the first line, I see no other way but to loop it:

```
sed ':a;/plot/!{n;ba;};:b;n;s///;bb'
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you are ok with an `awk` solution, could you please try following.

```
awk '/plot/ && ++count==1{print;next} !/plot/' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code.

```
awk '                         ##Starting awk program from here.
/plot/ && ++count==1{         ##Checking condition if string plot is present and variable count value is 1 then do following.
  print                       ##Printing the current line.
  next                        ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}                             ##Closing BLOCK for above condition.
!/plot/                       ##Checking condition if string plot is NOT present then do print of that line.
' Input_file                  ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

***NOTE:*** In case you want to save output into Input_file itself then append `> temp  && mv temp Input_file` to above code.